# Binary storage of floating point values (between 0 and 1) using less than 4 bytes?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I need to store a massive numpy vector to disk. Right now the vector that I am trying to store is ~2.4 billion elements long and the data is `float64`. This takes about 18GB of space when serialized out to disk.

If I use `struct.pack()` and use `float32` (4 bytes) I can reduce it to ~9GB. I don't need anywhere near this amount of precision disk space is going to quickly becomes an issue as I expect the number of values I need to store could grow by an order of magnitude or two.

I was thinking that if I could access the first 4 significant digits I could store those values in an int and only use 1 or 2 bytes of space. However, I have no idea how to do this efficiently. Does anyone have any idea or suggestions?

Comment: what precision and range do you need?

Comment: I don't understand your numbers, `float32 == 4 bytes`, and `float16 == 2 bytes` in my books ...

Comment: I second @BasSwinckels question ...

Comment: And can you tell anything about the content of the data, does it show any particular pattern? There are compression schemes that are optimized for storing floating point time series of physical signals (think mp3 or flac for sound). For signals that only vary slowly, taking the differential will reduce the dynamic range a lot. Standard compression schemes for data (zip, bz2, ...) will not work as well.

Comment: @Daniel only about 4-8 significant digits. The data is cosine similarity values so the data ranges from 0 to 1. I am using pdist from numpy, and when I save the array using numpy.save the data is about twice the size as the file I generate using struct.pack("f") to store the values. Yes I am probably mixing up what types are being used and the storage associated with them. Maybe its a float64 vs float32 difference. Either way, I am storing way more data than I need...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your data is between 0 and 1, and 16bit is enough you can save the data as uint16:

```
data16 = (65535 * data).round().astype(uint16)
```

and expand the data with

```
data = data16 / 65535.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, I'd recommend against using `float16`, but for what it's worth, it's quite easy to do.

However, the `struct` module can't convert to/from 16-bit floats.

Therefore, you'll need to do something similar to:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(0, 1, 1000)

x = x.astype(np.float16)
with open('outfile.dat', 'w') as outfile:
    x.tofile(outfile)
```

Note that "outfile.dat" is exactly 2000 bytes - two bytes per item.  `tofile` just writes the raw, "packed" binary data to disk.  There's no header, etc, and no difference in the output between using it and the `struct` module.

Answer (score 0):

Use `struct.pack()` with the `f` type code to get them into 4-byte packets.